# Rails Address Format Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, street-address

I am trying to create a helper that will format an address from 5 columns (add1,add2, add3,add4,add5) so that it will compact any nulls and display on screen as such

```
Add1,
Add3,
Add4,
Add5
```

(add 2 was skipped as it was null)

I created the following helper to assemble and skip any nulls but I can not introduce a new line break. Any ideas?

```
def delivery_address(customer)
@customer =  Customer.find(customer.id) 

if @customer.del_address1.blank? 
  deladdress = "No Delivery Address"
else

    deladdress = @customer.del_address1 
    deladdress = deladdress + "</br>"

  if customer.del_address2.blank?
    else 
    deladdress = deladdress + @customer.del_address2 + ","

  end

  if @customer.del_address3.blank?
    else 
    deladdress = deladdress +  @customer.del_address3 + ","

  end

  if @customer.del_address4.blank?
    else 
    deladdress = deladdress +  @customer.del_address4 + ","

  end

  if @customer.del_address5.blank?
    else 
    deladdress = deladdress +  @customer.del_address5

  end

end

end
```

Comment: What does "introduce a new line break" mean? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Add a line break eg  <br>  or carriage return.

Comment: @ChrisNash `<br>` and `\n` are two different things. Which do you want? Please be clear.

Comment: @tomLord I want which ever one is going to give me an address block of text over multiple lines. I have tried both in my helper and couldn't get either to work. Obvs I had the syntax wrong

Comment: As your function is a view helper, a `<br/>` tag would be fitting.

Comment: Just in case this is helpful, the standard USPS multiline address format has no commas at the end of any address line. If the delivery address is supposed to read like it would on a package for delivery in the US, the trailing commas should be omitted. Reference -> https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_001.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One important advise: You should not do any database queries inside a view helper. This should only be done in the controller. An active record should already be passed into the helper function. So this line

```
@customer =  Customer.find(customer.id)
```

can be removed.

```
def delivery_address(customer)
  # Use a guard clause, this reduces if nesting
  return 'No Delivery Address' if customer.del_address1.blank? 

  # Collect all parts    
  parts = [customer.del_address1, customer.del_address2, customer.del_address3, customer.del_address4, customer.del_address5]

  # Remove all empty parts.
  # Using a bang method is lighter on memory allocation
  # and will speed up performance.
  parts.reject!(&:blank?) 

  parts.join('<br/>').html_safe
end
```

Comment: Thanks but on the page this is only showing the 5 lines of the address on 1 line and not split over multiple lines as I would expect.

Comment: Ah. I forgot the html_safe call. That should work now

Comment: I just reloaded the page and the address was perfect - that brings joy to my heart Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def delivery_address(customer)
  @customer =  Customer.find(customer.id)
  return "No Delivery Address" if @customer.del_address1.blank?

  [
    @customer.del_address1,
    @customer.del_address2,
    @customer.del_address3,
    @customer.del_address4,
    @customer.del_address5
  ].reject(&:blank?).join(",\n")
end
```

Rather than writing 5 `if` statements, you can put all values into an array, then delete any blank values.

Note that my code here is based on yours, but is not quite what your question asked for:

> it will compact any nulls

An empty string is also considered `blank?` (but `"" != nil`). So this method will also skip these values.

If you did only want to ignore `nil` values, but keep empty strings, then replace `reject(&:blank?)` with `compact`.

Comment: was about to make an aswer with compact rather than blank to match what OP asked (null values), nice edit

Comment: Thanks Tom, however on the page this displays as such
    23 Taylor Road<br/>Bradford<br/>BD6 1BH

Comment: @ChrisNash As mentioned above, you can use `.html_safe`. Without a [mcve] (i.e. in this case, how is the method being called?) of the problem, I had no way of knowing whether this solution was complete :)